# Is it possible to use a trait method without bringing it into scope?

Tags: rust, scope, traits

The use of `use` in Rust so far seems pretty simple - everything is already "imported" (in the sense that other languages use the word), `use` just brings them into scope.

However, for `trait`s, this seemingly falls apart. To use a trait's methods on a struct, the said trait must be in scope.

So I thought, if the behavior of `use` be consistent, then there must be another, more verbose way of calling trait methods.
So I tried:

```rust
fn main() {
 some_obj.TraitName::trait_method();
}
```

However this doesn't seem to compile. So is there a way to do this or is `use` inconsistent in this sense?

EDIT: `TraitName` is the full path of the trait, i.e `some_obj.module_1::TraitName::trait_method()`.

Comment: `TraitName::trait_method (&some_obj)`?

Comment: Well yeah, while that would work, that would break the whole dot chain. I was hoping a syntax similar to the one I showed would be applicable.

Comment: Personally don't know of any way except of using fully qualified syntax. One workaround could be to limit the scope and import trait: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=550801a3b425ac51cedc320a66f78276

Answer (score 3):

You could use fully qualified syntax:

```rust
 <Type as crate::mod::TraitName>::trait_method(object);
```

as example:

```rust
mod m {
    pub trait Foo {
        fn foo(&self) {}
    }

    impl<T> Foo for T {}
}

fn main() {
    let x = 10u32;
    <u32 as m::Foo>::foo(&x);
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=5f5fdc0529d30145a517f2239ebff987)

Or just let the compiler elide the types:

```rust
m::Foo::foo(&x);
```

Comment: I already knew this is possible. However, when you're method chaining, this breaks the entire flow. At that point, it's just easier to just add a `use` and be done with it. This isn't a real issue anyways, I was just asking because I was curious.

Comment: @VivekYadav, uhm, yes, it is not suitable to actually chain them. But I dont see the problem on using `use` really.

Comment: None really, like i said, I was just curious, as I have been noticing some inconsistencies in Rust. I'm also thinking to ask a similar question but about the inconsistency in allowing variable shadowing, but not function name overloading (though both signify the same thing - similar task but done with a different data type).